# Generating SVG image in Java

Tags: java, svg, vector, graphics

Although I have a very simple question I have not found any good answer anywhere.

I would like to write a program (in Java) to create an SVG Image.

For example I would like to create an SVG file which would contain red circle with some set radius.

I would truly appreciate if someone could help me to find some tutorial for this kind of work. I spent a lot of time searching but I could not find anything. (Maybe I am using wrong keywords or something...)

Thank you

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: you can use ImageIO to generate image. are you trying to convert an image to an svg ? Or want to generate another different image ?

Comment: Try [batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)

Comment: take a look at [Array to SVG, flexible algorithm with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46472018/2521214) you can (port from PHP or C++ to JAVA)  adapt those examples to suite your needs. You just create a text file as output

Answer (score 4):

It depends what additional requirements you have.  SVG files are XML files, so they are really just plain text files.  You can create them with any of the standard IO methods.  For example, this Java program satisfies your question:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   System.out.println("<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\" width=\"100\" height=\"100%\">");
   System.out.println("<circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"30\" fill=\"red\">");
   System.out.println("</svg>");
}
```

Perhaps you want to create and manipulate DOM objects, similar to how you do it in Javascript.  If that is the case, then you may want to try the Apache Batik library.  You should be able to find plenty of tutorials on how to use that, both here on SO, and elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score -13):

First of all, you should learn what Scalable Vector Graphics are and how you can create them in general. This tutorial may help you with getting into this topic: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp

To create a SVG in Java you need to know about I/O Methods in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

But the most important step is to try by yourself and don`t just ask for people doing stuff for you!