# Why doesn't SVG tag <symbol> work properly?

Tags: svg, vector, graphics, symbols

I have svg:

```
<svg _ngcontent-c23="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<symbol id="edeb4def-6ea8-3f8a-809d-40ca8ce3bddb" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="Chelsea" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" >
    <path d="M119,3 L81,3 L81,3.78138753 C81,6.6620789 99.9873181,18 99.9873181,18 C99.9873181,18 119,6.6620789 119,3.78138753 L119,3 Z" fill="#D31818" id="inside-neck"></path>
</g>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

It doesn't work in my app and online svg viewers ([exp1](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.html), [exp2](https://www.freecodeformat.com/svg-editor.php))
If I change `<symbol>` tag to `<g>`, it works.

Comment: What are you expecting? A symbol is a reusable template, on its own it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Thank you, Robert! I got it =)

Comment: take a look at this: [Array to SVG, flexible algorithm with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46472018/2521214) and look ho I generate the SVG ... in order to see them correctly you need to have properly set the `viewbox` and path properties ... so extract the format from my example and try if it works for your path ... but as you already figured out the path should be encapsulated in `<g>` tag not a `<symbol>` ...